# counting paths for a given situation

Tags: python

i have a question regarding a situation where we are asked to write a python function for counting the number of paths. The question is as such:

A robot is located at the top-left corner of a **3x7** gird. the robot can only **move down one square** or **right one square** at any point in time and cannot move in any other direction. the robot is trying to reach the bottom-right corner of the grid.

Write a python function, **countPaths** which returns a table(a list of lists), **paths**. Each item in the table paths is the number of possible paths the robot can take from the **Start** position to the position corresponding to the item in the table. For example, **paths[0][0]** = 1 and **paths[2][6]**=28. 
[image]

Here is something i tried out but it needs some correction. I'm fairly new to python and i need some help correcting the code.

```
def countPaths(row,column):
    row = 1
    column = 1
    for row in range(1,n):
        for column in range(1,n):
            (n_row-1 + n_column-1)
    return paths
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has some good ideas, but you do not implement them correctly. You are correct in adding two array values to get a new array value, and you are right in using two nested `for` loops. But you overwrite the values of `row` and `col` in the first two lines inside the function and try to use `n` which is never defined. You also do not access the previous values of the array properly. Finally, you do not take into account the fact that the left column and top row do not add values together but simply have the value `1`.

Here is code that works. Let me know if you need an explanation of any part of it.

```
def countpaths(row, column):
    result = [[1] * column for r in range(row)]
    for r in range(1, row):
        for c in range(1, column):
            result[r][c] = result[r][c-1] + result[r-1][c]
    return result

paths = countpaths(3,7)
for r in paths:
    print(r)
print(paths[0][0])
print(paths[2][6])
```

This prints

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28]
1
28
```

Answer (score 0):

**Mathematical formulation:**
To reach element [x][y] the robot needs to do x+y moves. So he has x+y choose x options to distribute his x steps right onto his x+y moves.

Hence paths[x][y] = (x+y)!/(x!+y!)

**And here is the python implementation:**

```
from math import factorial as fac
def countPaths():
    noRows=3
    noCols=7
    paths=[]
    for row in range(0,noRows):
        #uncomment to see how the list of lists is build
        #print(paths)
        paths.append([])
        for col in range(0,noCols):
            paths[row].append( int( fac(row+col)/fac(row)/fac(col)))
    return paths

paths=countPaths()
print('\n\nresult:')
print(paths)
```

**Result:**

```
result:
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28]]
```

Just use the print command to follow the content of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive implementation:

```
rowLength = 3
colLength = 7
count = 0
path = []
paths = []

def countPaths(row,col):
    global count
    global path
    global paths

    if (row,col) in path:
        return
    else:
        path.append((row,col))    

    if row == rowLength and col == colLength:
        count += 1
        print ("Reached end, Path followed: ",path)
        paths.append(path)
        path.pop()
        return
    if row > rowLength or col > colLength:
        path.pop()
        return

    # Go down
    countPaths(row+1, col)

    # Go right
    countPaths(row, col+1)

    path.pop()
    return

countPaths(0,0)
```